# Change E-mail configuration in setting.py

Tags: django

I have configuration to e-mail in setting.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'Host'
EMAIL_PORT = 'NrPost'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'User'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'Pass***'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

And with correct data it work. But now I have data in  DATABASES. Where I can change value email_host etc. from database?
I need send a mail. Code:

```
ValueOpt = Options.objects.get(id=1)
try:
        connection = mail.get_connection(
            host = ValueOpt.NameHost,
            port = ValueOpt.NamePort,
            username = ValueOpt.NameMail,
            password = ValueOpt.PassMail,
        )
        connection.Open()

    msg = EmailMessage(
        'Title',
        '---------------- <br />' + TextMail + '<br />----------------',
        str(ValueOpt.NameMail),
        [str(ValueOpt.NameToSend),str(ValueOpt.NameMail) ],
        connection=connection,
    )
    msg.content_subtype = 'html'
    msg.send()
    connection.Close()
except Exception as e:
    return HttpResponse(e)
```

But mail is isn't send. Exception error : 'EmailBackend' object has no attribute 'Open'

Comment: You should not try to change your settings.py file from data in your database which may be inputted by potentially malicious users. Settings.py is meant to initially setup before running the server.

Comment: Ok I understand. But how I can sendmail by value from database?

Comment: Build your [own backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#defining-a-custom-email-backend). The default Django [SMTP backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#smtp-backend) that you're using is a good starting point, since you'll be doing similar stuff.

Comment: But maybe you should explain why you need this or what you're trying to achieve, because there's generally no need to change such settings dynamically. Especially if wrong data is entered in the db, how are your users going to receive the emails for password reset, email verification etc...?